# Where can I find the LEGO fire dept. logo in high resolution or in vector format

Tags: city

I want print a high resolution version of the Lego fire department shield (the shield with three flames that is used on all Lego fire trucks). When I search with Google, I find mostly low resolution images.

The best would be a vector image (like SVG) or a high resolution bitmap image (PNG or the like). Has anyone created a high resolution image like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Going on advice from [InkBlend](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/#comment1911_1019) I converted the logo to a vector graphic from a sticker sheet scanned in for the 7945 Fire Station set on [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=7945stk01).

I used [VectorMagic](http://vectormagic.com) to convert the file and automaticaly create paths. The SVG vector file can be downloaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?q889gt9oxtx0u51). If you don't have an image editor that supports vector editing, you can also download a [high-resolution PNG graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buMMI.png) (267.33 kB).

You could also try scanning in a sticker sheet from a set that has the sticker. With Illustrator, Photoshop or any other similar image editors, trace around the design using a pen tool and fill in the colours. Using the scanned image as a reference.

If you're having trouble finding a suitable image, I would also recommend looking at the [LEGO City product page](http://city.us.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx) for wallpaper downloads and illustrations.

Comment: This is a good image.  The OP wants a vector graphic, so I would recommend editing the image with the GIMP to get just the logo, than importing that as a bitmap into Inkscape and path tracing it into a vector image.

Comment: @InkBlend: I've updated my answer to include both a vector file and a high resolution image.