# How to make custom LEGO signs, newspapers, etc.

Tags: stickers

I have several ideas, but I am finding it hard to get started. What I am interested in is making my own [decals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decal) for signs, newspapers, artwork for the walls and others. So far I haven't had any luck.  Is there a site that has LEGO clip art backgrounds, lettering, etc.?

Comment: BrickLink has a huge collection of [sticker sheets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=160&sortBy=Y&sortAsc=A&catType=P&v=2) which can be used for inspiration. My answer from a [previous question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1019/132) explains how you can obtain decals from existing sticker sheets.

Comment: Your question is vague. Are you having difficulty with inspiration, artwork, printing or something else? What do you want "LEGO clipart backgrounds" for, and what do you think they are?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't exactly know what you mean buy a sign like one that he/her can hold or a sign in the ground? Moving onto the newspaper you can get white sticky clay and get two white 6x5 pieces or a size you like and fill in the crack in the middle then put one piece of clay in the Lego persons hand and shape it in a Lego rectangle size
 Hope this helped